# Using self hosted Wordpress with a 301 redirect

Tags: php, html, apache, wordpress, web

Recently I've been working to develop a multi-user Wordpress site with Wordpress 3.0 however at the moment we are iso.g one server to showcase preview static content in a subdirectory while multi WP is in the root directory.

My question however is how to keep the root directory hidden from the publc.  Curntly I have a PHP index file handling he redirect howevwer as WP has its own index file I waned to ask about any possible alternatives.

Thanks very much for any assistance,

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to want to do it with an `.htaccess` file. However, Wordpress has one of those too, so rename the current `.htaccess` file to `.htaccess.orig` (or whatever you want... but don't delete it) and then create your new `.htaccess` file with your 301 redirect.

Then whenever you are done, just rename everything back to the way it was.